# website page has unwanted horizontal scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a annoying bug with my website where when i preview my website with live server, there is a unwanted horizontal scroll bar when there is no content in the scrolled area. I am a new developer so i come across many errors which mostly i can resolve. Can someone help me with the error in my code which is causing the horizontal scroll bar.`

This is my HTML

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

h1 {
  color: pink;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  color: pink;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding-left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.titles {
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

header ul li {
  color: pink;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

header ul {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  left: 400px;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
<div class="titles">
  <h1>HI, I'm Anas and I'm a Junior Webdeveloper.</h1>
  <p>
    I have recently started coding and I am looking to persue a career in software engineering and web developing.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `position: relative; left: 400px;` is pushing the header to the right by 400px. This is likely not wanted?

Comment: shall i remove this?

Comment: i want to centre the header ul but i did it using position relative and using left: 400px;

Comment: Don't use `position: relative` to center it.

Comment: Open your dev tools and inspect the element, everything should be there if you look closely at the CSS while the element is highlighted.

Answer (score 3):

Adjust your header ul css to leverage flexbox so you don't need the padding-left: 400px, which is causing the unwanted horizontal scroll:

```
header ul {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: thank you but now what shall i use to center the ul to the middle of my page

Comment: Instead of 'justify-content: flex-end', you can use 'justify-content: center' to center the list. For spacing, you can play around with align-items property. Learn more about flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

This happens in HTML when the content goes beyond the width of the screen. A quick fix is too add 
`overflow-x:hidden`
So in your style tag add

```
body{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

To read more on the overflow property
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp
Happy Coding!

Comment: I had the same bug, I had no H-scroll in the local host but had it in the live site, tried something and just a min ago a found a solution... body{ max-width: 100%; }